# Can I speed up performance of a multiple transparent videos using WebGL rather than Video?

Tags: html, performance, video

Similar to [Webgl animated texture performance versus canvas drawImage performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208715/webgl-animated-texture-performance-versus-canvas-drawimage-performance)

I was experimenting with creating a [visual novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_novel)'s UI where I have the characters in an animation loop.  Rather than having multiple variants I was thinking having a single large resolution video that I can zoom in and out as needed.

What I found (and also expected) is that using the `<video>` tag to display them taxes the system and I think GPU as well since the video tag itself is being hardware accelerated for rendering.

My question is: 
Rather than having the videos in DOM, I would draw it in a canvas but then I'm wondering if this method will consume less GPU/CPU resources? Also If possible... how would one do that?